# Pass Python list to concatenate_videoclips function in Moviepy module

Tags: python, video, moviepy

**Purpose:**

1. Build a python list of video files in a directory
2. Open video clips (Understood requirement of moviepy)
3. Call combine_clips function and pass 'clips' list (Error occurs here.)
4. Write combined clips to single video file

**Error:**

```
"concatenate.py", line 71, in concatenate_videoclips
tt = np.cumsum([0] + [c.duration for c in clips])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'duration'"
```

**Script:**

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import *

def clips_list():
    clips = []
    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if file.endswith(".mov"):
            clips.append(file)
    open_clips(clips)

def open_clips(clips):
    for clip in clips:
        VideoFileClip(clip)
    combine_clips(clips)

def combine_clips(clips):
    video = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose')

def output_video(video):
    video.write_videofile('ct_01.mp4')

clips_list()
```

Question: Why does "concatenate_videoclips()" accept a hardcoded list but fail when I pass it a list.

Comment: always put **FULL** error message - there is many usefull information.

Comment: use `print()` and see what you have on list - as for me not `VideoFileClip` but filenames.

Comment: you create `VideoFileClip(clip)` but you don't add this to list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create `VideoFileClip(clip)` but you don't add to list so you send list with filenames to `concatenate_videoclips`

You need `new_list` in

```
def open_clips(clips):

    new_list = []

    for clip in clips:
        new_list.append(VideoFileClip(clip))

    combine_clips(new_list)
```

---

**EDIT:** shorter:

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import *

clips = []

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.endswith(".mov"):
        clips.append(VideoFileClip(filename))

video = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose')
video.write_videofile('ct_01.mp4')
```

Comment: Thank you @furas! This makes since and works. I will post the entire error message next time. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried this but I get this error: `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`. No idea why. If you know the cause, can you please let me know?

Comment: @JoeT.Boka I would have to see FULL error message - you can create new question. Moviepy use external program `ffmpeg` so maybe you have to install it. See: http://ffmpeg.org/